# sendBroadcast when message received using smack

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I am trying to use smack API for my chat application. 
What done so far:

My service for listening incoming messages:

```
        chatmanager.addChatListener(
                new ChatManagerListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void chatCreated(Chat chat, boolean createdLocally) {
                        if (!createdLocally)
                            chat.addMessageListener(myMessageListener);
                    }
                });


class MyMessageListener implements  ChatMessageListener {


    @Override
    public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
        String body = message.getBody();
        if (body != null && !body.isEmpty()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(MY_ACTION);
            intent.putExtra("message", body);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

My receiver class :

```
public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    private ChatArrayAdapter chatArrayAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        Log.d("receiveddddd", message);

        chatArrayAdapter.add(new ChatMessage(true,message));
        chatArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

My activity used for registering Receiver :

```
protected void onResume() {
        messageReceiver = new MessageReceiver();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(XMPPService.MY_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(messageReceiver, intentFilter);
        super.onResume();
    }
```

This is how I send message using my android app :

```
//listener is the object of MyMessageListener class



    Chat chat = chatmanager.createChat("username@" + SERVICE,listener);

            try {
                chat.sendMessage(messageBody);
            } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I am using Pidgin as my second client.

**Problem :**

1) When I start the chat from pidgin. I am able to receive and send successfully but it failed to receive messages when I start chatting from my android app to Pidgin. I get this error while receiving messages :

```
Exception in packet listener
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:312)
            at fbcrush.fbcrush.XMPPClientSmack.XMPPService$MyMessageListener.processMessage(XMPPService.java:72)
            at org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.Chat.deliver(Chat.java:180)
```

Line number 72 is sendBroadcast(intent) in my MyMessageListener class

Comment: Where do you Register and unregistered your message listener? Might be a case of your listener being orphaned and still receiving messages but being unable to act on it since your context has been prepared for being freed.

Comment: registering onStart and unregistering onResume.

Comment: onStart matches with onStop not onResume :) try matching with onResume / onPause instead.

Comment: @Johanshaogun :- Yes I agree with you ....@lalit you need to register the listener on **onstart** method and unregistered the listener on **onStop** method

There is no way to unregistered the listener on **On resume** method while your activity is in foreground.